# Can Wubi install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, windows, 64-bit, wubi

I am trying to develop for Android on Ubuntu but it requires a 64 bit version. Can Wubi install a 64 bit version or do I need to do a regular install?

Answer (score 1):

Wubi will automatically download and install [the 64-bit version of Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Why_is_the_AMD64_version_of_Ubuntu_being_downloaded_and_installed.3F) if you are running Windows 64-bit.